# How do I install uudecode?

Tags: installation

I am using Ubuntu v12.10, 64bit, US English and am new to Linux and Ubuntu; hence detailed instructions are welcome.

Could someone show me where and how to download uudecode? Also specific commands on how to run/install uudecode would be most helpful.

The error message is as follows:

```
Validating available tools...

ERROR: Required utility missing: uudecode. Please install this
utility before using this Intelligent Updater package.
```

Comment: Have you tried the method mentioned in the answer below? Because if you solved your problem, then you should mark the answer as correct.

Comment: @ Lucio: Thanks for the reminder. I have marked it as correct.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

uudecode is in the package *sharutils*

Install it with the package manager or 
start a terminal and type this command

```
sudo apt-get install sharutils
```